# Set button name from enum_

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a lot of buttons on a WPF window. To avoid coding the same click event over and over again I would like them to all trigger the same method and take the appropriate action based on which button I call.

I know I can cast the sender to a button and then check the name and route the code from there, but then I have to have all the names hard coded, which could be a mess if buttons get renamed a some stage.

What is a better way of doing this? Can I for example name the button from an enum? Or is it possible to get the button names for the check by actually referencing the buttons directly?

Something like this maybe?

```
private void btnAddTerminatorElement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MsoAutoShapeType shapeType;

        switch (((Button)sender).Name)
        {
            case this.btnAddTerminatorElement.Name:
                shapeType = MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeFlowchartTerminator;
                break;

        }

        CreateChartElement(this.targetWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeFlowchartTerminator, 100, 100, 50, 50));
    }
```

But this doesn't work as is because a constant is needed for the comparison...

Comment: Have you tried using the Tag property to determine which Button was clicked? That way you don't have to worry about name changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only good way I have come up with so far is not to use a switch statement, but to go for separate if blocks in the event function to check the caller name. Something like this:

```
private void btnAddTerminatorElement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        MsoAutoShapeType shapeType = MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle;

        if (sender == this.btnAddTerminatorElement)
            shapeType = MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeFlowchartTerminator;

        if (sender == this.btnAddDecisionElement)
            shapeType = MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeFlowchartDecision;

        CreateChartElement(this.targetWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(shapeType, 100, 100, 50, 50));
    }
```

The only method I can think of so far that is robust enough to cope with renaming the buttons. If there are any alternatives I'd be most interested in hearing about them.

Comment: What about having a dictionary instead of the chain of ifs? It'd be easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to get enum from string. Then Your switch will work.

Edit:

I should explain it maybe a little more: You could create enum with button names as values, and then convert Name to enum and do switch.

Hm... even easier solution: You could use MsoAutoShapeType values as button Names or Tags, and then convert it to enum in click handler, eliminating switch clause.

Comment: I like the idea of using the msoAutoShapeType values for the button names, but I can't figure out how to do it. As far as I can tell the button name can only be a string? If you know how to do it, could you please provide an example?